# Kubernetes pods logs are not getting by kubectl logs command

Tags: kubernetes, logging, gcloud

I am using a WordPress site build with Kubernetes deployment. In the deployment I have only one container pod.  Could you please clarify the possible reasons on the logs are not getting via kubectl logs command. I have tried docker logs on the container also, which is also showing the same output.

```
#~$ kubectl logs -f <pod_name> -n <namespace>
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xx.xx.xx.xx. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

This is the only content in logs even after accessing the domain.

```
# docker logs -f <k8s_container_name>
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xx.xx.xx.xx. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl logs` show the default **STDOUT** and **STDERR**

You need to write the `file_put_contents('php://stderr', 'Your text goes to STDERR',FILE_APPEND);`

at least append in file and you read from there or else if you developing php WordPress you can push logs to external logging also.

Read more at : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php & https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/